# Maple: How to parse such CSV (Comma Separated Values) document?

Tags: parsing, csv, matrix, document, maple

So I have a large txt file with such contents (like 20mbs long)

```
20 30 40 550 60 70 80 91
20 30 40 50 60 70 80 92
20 30 40 50 60 70 80 93
20 30 40 50 64 70 80 90
20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
20 30 40 40 60 70 80 90
40 30 40 50 60 70 80 90

4 5 6 6

20 30 40 50 60 70 80 91
20 30 40 50 60 70 80 92
20 30 40 50 60 70 80 93
2 30 40 50 64 70 80 90
20 30 20 50 60 70 80 90
20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
20 30 40 40 60 70 80 90
40 30 40 50 60 70 80 90

4 5 1 6

20 30 40 50 60 70 80 91
20 30 40 50 60 70 80 92
20 30 40 50 60 70 80 93
20 30 40 50 64 70 80 90
20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
20 1 40 40 60 70 80 90
40 30 40 50 60 70 80 90

4 5 6 1
```

I want to get out of that document an array of matrices 8x8 and an array of matrices 1*4 is such thing possible and how to do it?

Comment: Your given data is separated by spaces, not by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following produces a table M of 8x8 Matrices, and a table V of 1x4 row Vectors.

You could optionally create M and V up front as Arrays of size n. Just uncomment those lines. You can see that it is hard-coded for 100 Matrix-Vector pairs of scans. Increase n as you wish. It will stop anyway when it fails to scan the next item, by detecting the fscanf failures and breaking out of the loop.

My example used a plaintext data file that contained just three pairs of Matrix and Vector, and it did a break when failing on the fourth pair of scan attempts.

```
restart:
Z:="C://TEMP//mydata.txt":

fclose(Z);

#M:=Array(1..100):
#V:=Array(1..100):

for i from 1 to 100 do
   try
      M[i]:=fscanf(Z,"%{8,8}ldm")[1];
      V[i]:=fscanf(Z,"%{4}ldr")[1];
   catch "end of input encountered":
      break;
   end try;
end do;

M[2]; # returns the 2nd entry (a 8x8 Matrix) of M
V[2]; # returns the 2nd entry (a 1x4 row Vector) of V
```